# classList.remove and .add not working for some reason

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

When toggling the switch I get these errors from the browser console. For some reason it does not work and I can't solve why this won't work I am just starting Javascript so don't me mad at me if I did something stupid.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove')
    at getValue (darkModeSwitch.js:8)
    at window.onload (index.html:17)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
    at getValue (darkModeSwitch.js:13)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:26)
```

```js
const body = document.body
const anchor = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
const darkModeToggle = document.getElementById('darkModeToggle');

function getValue(){
  if (darkModeToggle.checked) {
      body.classList.remove("lightmode")
      anchor.classList.remove("lightmode")
      console.log("checked")
  } else{
      console.log("not checked")
      body.classList.add("lightmode")
      anchor.classList.add("lightmode")
  }
};
```

```css
.lightmode{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="kapcsolat/kapcsolat.html?version=691">Kapcsolat</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects/projects.html?version=691">Projektek</li>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html?version=692">Kezdőlap</a></li>
        <li><label class="switch"><input onclick="getValue()" id="darkModeToggle" type="checkbox" checked><span class="slider round"></span></label><script src="scripts/darkModeSwitch.js"></script>
        </li>
        <h1 class="jayden" style="float: left;"><a class="jayden" href="index.html?version=-23424893215">jayden.hu</a></h1>  
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is that JS code `const body = document.body` etc - getting executed AFTER the page loads? try wrapping your variable initializations in `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {`

Comment: <script>
        window.onload = function() {
        getValue();
        };
        </script> I have it like this.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName` returns array`[]` of element that's why `anchor.classList` is undefined . You should specifically find element that you want toggle the classes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with Body but with `anchor` .
You use `getElementsByTagName` which returns a List ( array ) and not a single element even though you have a single `a` the `anchor` constant value will be an array with length 1.

Either use querySelector either by ID either select first item `document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]` -> not really best practice.

Or, if you have multiple anchor tags, just loop over them

See below

```js
const body = document.body
const anchor = document.querySelectorAll("a.jayden");
const darkModeToggle = document.getElementById('darkModeToggle');

function getValue() {
  if (darkModeToggle.checked) {
    body.classList.remove("lightmode")
    anchor.forEach(a => a.classList.remove("lightmode"))
    console.log("checked")
  } else {
    console.log("not checked")
    body.classList.add("lightmode")
     anchor.forEach(a => a.classList.add("lightmode"))
  }
};
```

```css
.lightmode {
  background:blue
  }
  a.lightmode {
    color: white
    }
```

```html
<input onclick="getValue()" id="darkModeToggle" type="checkbox" checked />
<a class="jayden" href="#" >jayden.hu</a>
<a class="jayden" href="#" >jayden.hu</a>
```

Comment: it doesn't return an array it returns a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

Comment: @pilchard what is the difference ( especially in this specific situation ) between HTMLCollection and an array ?

Comment: Thanks, this did work, but it does not work if I have an another class on an element as well. How do I solve this?

Comment: The differences are significant: the first being that an HTMLCollection is live, meaning that changes made in the DOM are reflected in the collection and vice versa, next the collection doesn't implement any of the built in array methods (including forEach). (`querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList which does implement a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method, but it is seperate from the Array method of the same name)

Comment: @Jayden you want to select ALL anchor tags from your html ? also, why do you want to add same class to ' a ' as the one on body ? if you want to change somethig to all`a` elements depending on theme ( light/dark ) just add class to body and style the `a` elements ( and others ) depeding on body class dirrectly in CSS

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you're trying to modify the `classList` on multiple elements at once; your `anchor` variable contains an array of HTML elements (all of the anchors) rather than one specific element.

Thankfully, because CSS cascades, you don't need to change the class on any elements aside from your body. Just address the `a` elements like this in CSS so they inherit the `body`'s color:

```js
function getValue() {
  document.body.classList.toggle("lightmode")
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.lightmode {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="kapcsolat/kapcsolat.html?version=691">Kapcsolat</a></li>
    <li><a href="projects/projects.html?version=691">Projektek</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html?version=692">Kezdőlap</a></li>
    <li><label class="switch"><input onclick="getValue()" id="darkModeToggle" type="checkbox" checked><span class="slider round"></span></label></li>
    <h1 class="jayden" style="float: left;"><a class="jayden" href="index.html?version=-23424893215">jayden.hu</a></h1>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Anchor is an HTML collection which should be looped through:

```js
const body = document.body;

const anchor = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
const darkModeToggle = document.getElementById('darkModeToggle');

function getValue(){
 
if (darkModeToggle.checked) {

    console.log("checked");
    if(body.classList.contains("lightmode")){
    body.classList.remove("lightmode")
    }
   for(var a=0;a<anchor.length;a++){
    if(anchor[a].classList.contains("lightmode")){
    anchor[a].classList.remove("lightmode");
    }
   }
    
} else{

    
    console.log("not checked");
     if(!body.classList.contains("lightmode")){
    body.classList.add("lightmode")
   }
    for(var a=0;a<anchor.length;a++){
    if(!anchor[a].classList.contains("lightmode")){
    anchor[a].classList.add("lightmode");
    }
   }
}
}
```

```css
  .lightmode{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="kapcsolat/kapcsolat.html?version=691">Kapcsolat</a></li>
            <li><a href="projects/projects.html?version=691">Projektek</a></li>
            <li><a class="active" href="index.html?version=692">Kezdőlap</a></li>
            <li><label class="switch"><input onclick="getValue()" id="darkModeToggle" type="checkbox" checked><span class="slider round"></span></label><script src="scripts/darkModeSwitch.js"></script>
            </li>
            <h1 class="jayden" style="float: left;"><a class="jayden" href="index.html?version=-23424893215">jayden.hu</a></h1>  
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input onclick="getValue()" id="darkModeToggle" type="checkbox" checked />
<a class="jayden" href="#" >jayden.hu</a>
<a class="jayden" href="#" >jayden.hu</a>


//Make sure the elements exist on page
const body = document.body
const anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
const darkModeToggle = document.getElementById('darkModeToggle');
    
const getValue = () => {
  body.classList.toggle('lightmode'); // adds or removes class
  for (const anchor in anchors) {
    anchor.classList.toggle('lightmode'); // adds or removes class
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

to apply the styling change:

```
  .lightmode {
    background:blue
  }
  a.lightmode {
    color: white
  }
```

to:

```
  .lightmode:link {
    background:blue
  }
  a.lightmode {
    color: white
  }
```